# mouse and keyboard lags on new deployed UWP app

Tags: uwp

Deployed new UWP app to the store. Before I deployed the app, the app runs good on debug and release Mode. After I deployed to the windows store, the keyboard and mouse lags while typing. Is the issue related to my code or related to window 10?

While typing on the searchBox, I have implemented AutosuggestBox for showing results while typing on the textBox.

```
   private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                var searchTerm = sender.Text;
                using (var db = new DictContext())
                {
                    var results = db.Courses
                        .Where(c => c.Courses.courseItem.Contains(searchTerm))
                        .Select(c => c.Courses.courseItem)
                        .Distinct().ToList().Take(5);

                    sender.ItemsSource = results;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't device specific?

Comment: I have tested the deployed app on desktop and laptop.. There is still lagging while typing?

Comment: Were there any operations in your code when typing? If there're some code logic to deal with typing, you need to provide a [mcve].